# Reverse SSH Tunnel Connection

Tags: linux, shell, encryption, ssh

If I issue a command to set up a reverse shell:

```
grebwerd@bt:~$ ssh goldberd@whatever -R 10000:localhost:22.
```

I was wondering, when I issue this command, it connects me to grebwerd@whatever, what type of connection is being made between the two?

Is it a secure, encrypted connection?

1. `grebwerd@bt:~$ ssh grebwerd@whatever -R 10000:localhost:22`

   (what type of connect exists between grebwerd@bt and grebwerd@whatever, between these two commands)
2. `grebwerd@whatever:~$ ssh grebwerd@localhost -p 10000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traffic tunneled over ssh is sent within the encrypted ssh session.  Your second ssh command sets up an encrypted channel that is nested within another encrypted channel.